# Ffmpeg is installed, but I get the exception: You do not have ffmpeg installed on your machine

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I've searched for hours for a solution, but I haven't found one yet. Maybe someone here knows what is going wrong.

I'm trying to make a Bar Chart Race in Python. Although I have downloaded and installed Ffmpeg,
I keep on getting multiple errors:

```
    MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable; using Pillow instead.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/___/PycharmProjects/data_visualization/venv/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 251, in saving
        yield self
      File "/Users/___/PycharmProjects/data_visualization/venv/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1161, in save
        writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
      File "/Users/____/PycharmProjects/data_visualization/venv/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 549, in grab_frame
        renderer = self.fig.canvas.get_renderer()
    AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasBase' object has no attribute 'get_renderer'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/___/PycharmProjects/data_visualization/venv/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/bar_chart_race/_make_chart.py", line 435, in make_animation
        ret_val = anim.save(self.filename, fps=self.fps, writer=self.writer)
      File "/Users/___/PycharmProjects/data_visualization/venv/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1161, in save
        writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line         100, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/Users/___/PycharmProjects/data_visualization/venv/lib/python3.6/site-                        packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 253, in saving
        self.finish()
              File "/Users/____/PycharmProjects/data_visualization/venv/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 554, in finish
        self._frames[0].save(
            IndexError: list index out of range

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Exception: You do not have ffmpeg installed on your machine. Download
    ffmpeg from here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html.
    Matplotlib's original error message below:
    list index out of range
```

I've tried installing ffmpeg with conda, pip and homebrew. When I check the version, i get the following:

```
    ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
      built with clang version 9.0.1
      configuration: --prefix=/Users/___/opt/miniconda3 --cc=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang --disable-doc --disable-openssl --enable-avresample --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libx264 --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-version3 --enable-zlib --enable-libmp3lame
      libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
      libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
      libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
      libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
      libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
      libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
      libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
      libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
      libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

Here is the code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import bar_chart_race as bcr
    import os



    df = pd.read_csv('/Users/____/Documents/data/dummy_data.csv', delimiter=';', encoding="utf-8-sig")
    bcr.bar_chart_race(
        df=df,
        filename='test_win2.mov',
        orientation='h',
        sort='desc',
        n_bars=8,
        fixed_order=False,
        fixed_max=False,
        steps_per_period=50,
        interpolate_period=False,
        label_bars=True,
        bar_size=.95,
        period_label={'x': .99, 'y': .25, 'ha': 'right', 'va': 'center'},
        period_summary_func=lambda v, r: {'x': .99, 'y': .18,
                                  's': f'Totaal: {v.nlargest(8).sum():,.0f}',
                                  'ha': 'right', 'size': 8, 'family': 'Courier New'},
        perpendicular_bar_func='median',
        figsize=(3.5, 3),
        period_length=100,
        dpi=300,
        cmap='dark12',
        title='Title?',
        title_size='',
        bar_label_size=4,
        tick_label_size=4,
        shared_fontdict={'family': 'Helvetica', 'color': '.1'},
        scale='linear',
        writer=None,
        fig=None,
        bar_kwargs={'alpha': .3},
        filter_column_colors=False)
```

Comment: Please check if ffmpeg is added to path

Comment: @PrakashS I think the main error here is not a missing FFmpeg, but rather a too short (empty) list !?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PrakashS, but I do not know how to do this. Can you help?

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the index column when you read the **CSV** or **XlSX** file
in your case

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/____/Documents/data/dummy_data.csv', *index_col='index'*, delimiter=';', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

and replace **index** with the column you want to use as an index

refer to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#:%7E:text=are%20not%20allowed.-,index_col,-int%2C%20str%2C%20sequence) for more.